# Printing properties with .toLowerCase

Tags: java

The following code is given.

```
String myString = "Hello World";
myString.toLowerCase();
System.out.println(myString);
```

What my question regards the reason that the result that is printed isn't "hello world"

Is it because the second line doesn't REALLY do anything?
Would the proper syntax be (given the first line):

```
System.out.println(myString.toLowerCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in java

```
myString =myString.toLowerCase();
```

You have to get back the result by assigning.

```
String myString = "Hello World";  // your String
myString.toLowerCase();       // returning new String
System.out.println(myString); // Still your old String
```

So,

```
myString =myString.toLowerCase();// myString is now returned value.
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable in Java. That is why you need to re-assign the changed value returned by the `toLowerCase()` method back to `myString` variable.

```
String myString = "Hello World";
myString = myString.toLowerCase(); // re-assigning the changed value to myString
System.out.println(myString); // printing the new value
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following to get expected out put

```
    String myString = "Hello World";
    myString=myString.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(myString);
```

`toLowerCase()` s return type is `String` and that contains the lower case `String`. you should take return result from that method. Because String is immutable and `myString.toLowerCase()`  will return a new String witch in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

try  this

```
System.out.println(myString.toLowerCase());
```

String.toLowerCase() returns lower case String, it does not change the argument

Answer (score 0):

`String` variables are `immutable` i.e. you cannot change the object itself, but you can change the reference ofcourse.

Try this way,it will print newely assigned value

```
String myString = "Hello World";
myString = myString.toLowerCase(); 
System.out.println(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `String` is immutable in Java, the `myString.toLowerCase()` won't change anything in `myString` but just return a `new String` with all characters of `myString` converted to lower case using the rules of the default locale. If you explicitly assign it to the reference variable as shown below, it will refer to "hello world" object.

```
myString = myString.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, java.lang.String is an immutable object (it cannot be changed once it's created)

Try this way instead

```
String myString = "Hello World";
myString = myString.toLowerCase(); 
System.out.println(myString);
```